# wichtige oder wichtigen

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

Wir haben hier wichtig**e** Information**en** für Sie.

haben make accusative so why we cannot write

Wir haben hier wichtig**en** Information**en** für Sie.

?

Answer (score 0):

Adjetives only follow weak declension when an article (or pronoun working as an article) with an ending precedes them. This is not always true, but most of the time. Nominativ and Akkusativ Plural have **-e** as their strong and **-en** as their weak form.
Source: Dudenband 4 p.952